# Magento 2: How to wrapper link in new div?

Tags: magento-2.1, blocks, header, toplinks, topmenu

I need wrapper into a new div the block help create in the header.panel. I wrapped the block header-links in the new div and work, but the link custom doesn't wrapper in other div.

This is the code of my **default.xml**

```
    <referenceContainer name="header.panel">

        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current" name="help" before="div.login.menu">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">help</argument>
                <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">help</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>

        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current" name="navbar.brand">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">HOME</argument>
                <argument name="path" xsi:type="string"></argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>

        <container name="div.login.menu" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="login-menu" after="-">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Links" name="header.links">
            </block>
        </container>

        <container name="div.navbar.brand" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="navbar-brand" after="">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Current" name="navbar.brand">
            </block>
        </container>

    </referenceContainer>
```

I need wrapper the block help and the block navbar.brand in.

The result of my **default.xml** is this

```
<div class="panel header">
    <li class="nav item"><a href="">help</a></li>
    <li class="nav item"><a href="">HOME</a></li>

    <div class="login-menu">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="">Account</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

The wrapper of the header.links work, but the wrapper of the navbar.brand doesn't work.

Please, help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fix my problem.

```
        <container name="helplink.container" as="helplinkContainer" label="helplink Container" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="help-link">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current" name="linkhelp" after="top-search">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">help</argument>
                    <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">carvoe-help</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </container>
```